# JSP Before forEach loop getting one value

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am sure this another easy task but I am drawing a blank. I am dispalying an array but before I go into the forEach jstl I want to display one field. So here is what I have:

```
DirectorServlet.jsp (partial)
if(action.equals("list")){
    System.out.println("Inside DirectorServlet, listing");
    List<Director> directors = DirectorUtil.getDirectors();
    request.setAttribute("directors", directors);
    dispatcher="/directorlist.jsp";

    }
```

my directorlist.jsp file with forEach loop:

```
<h1>Directors</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped tablesorter">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="directors" items="${directors}">
            <tr>
                <td>${directors.name_dir}</td>
                <td>${directors.age_dir}</td>
                <td>${directors.title}</td>

                <td><a href="RatingServlet?action=addcomment&video_id=${videos.id}&title=${videos.title}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Comment</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="RatingServlet?action=details&video_id=${videos.id}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Details</a></td>
            </tr>


        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>

    </table>

I would like to replace the <h1>Directors</h1> to <h1>${directors.title}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you could set another request attribute directorsTitle.

```
 request.setAttribute("directorsTitle", directorsTitle);
```

and access it on the JSP like.

```
<h1><c:out value="${directorsTitle}"/></h1>
```

or if you want to access the list's any item then.

```
<c:out value="${directors[index].title}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access two times with the forEach and take only the first value in this way:

```
<c:forEach var="directors" items="${directors}" begin="1" end="1">
    <h1>${directors.title}</h1>
</c:forEach>

<table class="table table-striped tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="directors" items="${directors}">
        <tr>
            <td>${directors.name_dir}</td>
            <td>${directors.age_dir}</td>
            <td>${directors.title}</td>

            <td><a href="RatingServlet?action=addcomment&video_id=${videos.id}&title=${videos.title}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Comment</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="RatingServlet?action=details&video_id=${videos.id}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Details</a></td>
        </tr>


    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>

</table>
```